# Haskell: types, time, IO... general issues

Tags: haskell, time, io

(*sigh*) ...Haskell's type system is really kicking my butt, especially when throwing in the I/O issues on top.

I'm trying to measure performance speedups on some parallelized code.  I need to run it multiple times (e.g. `i=30`) with different parameters, then calculate averages etc.

So I start and end the timer before and after the parallelized code (`simulate` in the code below):

```
simulate :: Int -> Int -> [Double]
simulate numbuyers groupsize =
    let buyers = initTraders numbuyers minimum_price maximum_price
        sellers = initTraders numbuyers minimum_price maximum_price
        prices = doParallelTrades sellers buyers groupsize
    in prices

  
runNtimes :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO [(Double, Int, Double)]
runNtimes numbuyers groupsize i
    | i==0 = []
    | otherwise = do
        start <- getCurrentTime
        let prices = simulate numbuyers groupsize
        end <- getCurrentTime
        let dtime = realToFrac( diffUTCTime end start)
        return (average prices, length prices, dtime):(runNtimes numbuyers groupsize i-1)
```

The `runNtimes` function is giving me a slew of errors (I've already verified the simulate function works):

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [(Double, Int, Double)]’
                with actual type ‘[t0]’
    In the expression: []

zitraders-threaded.hs:162:21:
    No instance for (Fractional t1) arising from a use of ‘realToFrac’
    The type variable ‘t1’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      dtime :: t1 (bound at zitraders-threaded.hs:162:13)

zitraders-threaded.hs:163:9:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [(Double, Int, Double)]’
                with actual type ‘[m0 (Double, Int, t1)]’
    Relevant bindings include
      dtime :: t1 (bound at zitraders-threaded.hs:162:13)
    
zitraders-threaded.hs:163:56:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[m0 (Double, Int, t1)]’
                with actual type ‘IO [(Double, Int, Double)]’
    Relevant bindings include
      dtime :: t1 (bound at zitraders-threaded.hs:162:13)
```

I don't even know how to parse these errors, except that I'm pretty sure it's my lack of understanding types and I/O:`t0`? `t1`? `m0`?  What?

I read somewhere else on Stack Exchange to use `realToFrac` to get some computationally usable type out of `UTCtime` but given the errors above I'm not sure that's working either -- those errors aren't giving much information how it's not working.  It's frustrating.

I haven't even got to the part yet where I do something with the result from the `runNtimes` function -- basically just calculate average and standard deviation over the elements of the list (then print those out) -- but I'm expecting that returning an `IO` type will give me trouble there, too.

Comment: The error is because `runNtimes numbuyers groupsize i-1` is itself invalid, parentheses are required: `runNtimes numbuyers groupsize (i-1)` and that expr has type `IO X`, so you must run that computation first: `rs <- runNtimes ...; return ((..,..,..) : rs)`. Also, you have misunderstood the semantics of Haskell - `let prices = simulate numbuyers groupsize` will not force that expression to be evaluated at that point, instead it will be evaluated lazily (as all things in Haskell) - you can evaluate the expression with `print prices` or `Control.Exception.evaluate (sum prices)`.

Comment: Yes, it does work. You must adhere strictly to haskell syntax - function application binds stronger than operator application, so `return (a,b,c):rs` means `(return (a,b,c)):rs`, which is obviously wrong. You want `return ((a,b,c):rs)` - exactly as I write in my original comment.

Comment: You may want to try System.TimeIt.  Then you can do mapM_ (timeIt . putStrLn . show) [1..5] where putStrLn.show would be the function to test and [1..5] is a list of parameters

Comment: @atravers is there any concrete reason why you bounce this ancient question to the _active_ list with some small edits?

Comment: @atravers I just asked you a genuine question: _do you see enough value in this question, after all the years of it lying around unheeded, to merit the edit and/or that people think about an answer for it at last?_

Comment: @atravers look, I don't want anything with this question, whether answer or delete it or whatever. I just want to establish what's going on here. — Did you stumble on the question and thought it's bad / off-topic? Ok, so vote to close or flag it then. — You found it while browsing for some problem, and could use an answer to this question? Ok, so try to make a real improvement to the question that make it better answerable – but rather than editing this one, it might be preferrable to write your own question and then close this one as a duplicate of yours. — You _have_ an answer? Ok, write it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout personally, when stumbling upon a badly formatted question, I sometimes have to fix the formatting just so I can read it properly. Having done so, I sometimes feel it's a pity to have to through all that effort to waste.  ----- the minor edit feature "without bumping" was asked for on meta, and is still being ignored by SE.